# Deadlock issue with joblib

Tags: python, deadlock, joblib, bcolz

I would like to parallelize converting numpy array to bcolz carray with joblib, but when writing to carray, deadlock occurred.

The simplified code is here.

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import bcolz
from tqdm import tqdm
from pathlib import Path
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class BcolzConverter():
    """
    Save the output from a iterator without loading all images into memory.
    Does not return anything, instead writes data to disk.
    :it: iterator returns image and label
    :data_dir: The folder name to store the bcolz array representing the features in.
    :labels_dir: The folder name to store the bcolz array representing the labels in.
    """    
    def __init__(self, it, data_dir, labels_dir):
        self.it = it
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.labels_dir = labels_dir

    def convert(self):
        for directory in [self.data_dir, self.labels_dir]:
            if not Path(directory).exists():
                Path(directory).mkdir(parents=True)

        d, l = next(self.it)
        data = bcolz.carray(d, rootdir=self.data_dir, mode=self.mode)
        labels = bcolz.carray(l, rootdir=self.labels_dir, mode=self.mode)

        Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(self._process)(
            element, data, labels) for element in it)

        data.flush()
        labels.flush()

    @staticmethod
    def _process(element, data, labels):
        d, l = element
        data.append(d)
        labels.append(l)

converter = BcolzConverter(it, '../input/bcolz/data', '../input/bcolz/label', num_workers=4)
converter.convert()
```

The above program never stops unless user suspending.
The output is here. Program stacks due to waiter.aquire()

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-92dbce12edff> in <module>()
      3 it = DataIterator(df, label_onehot=True)
      4 converter = BcolzConverter(it, '../input/bcolz/data', '../input/bcolz/label', num_workers=4)
----> 5 converter.convert()

<ipython-input-115-fba84effdabc> in convert(self)
     66 
     67         Parallel(n_jobs=self.num_workers, verbose=10000)(delayed(self._process)(
---> 68             element, data, labels) for element in it)
     69 
     70         data.flush()

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    787                 # consumption.
    788                 self._iterating = False
--> 789             self.retrieve()
    790             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    791             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    697             try:
    698                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 699                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    700                 else:
    701                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    636 
    637     def get(self, timeout=None):
--> 638         self.wait(timeout)
    639         if not self.ready():
    640             raise TimeoutError

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in wait(self, timeout)
    633 
    634     def wait(self, timeout=None):
--> 635         self._event.wait(timeout)
    636 
    637     def get(self, timeout=None):

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    549             signaled = self._flag
    550             if not signaled:
--> 551                 signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
    552             return signaled
    553 

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    293         try:    # restore state no matter what (e.g., KeyboardInterrupt)
    294             if timeout is None:
--> 295                 waiter.acquire()
    296                 gotit = True
    297             else:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

It seems it is due to multiple processes trying to write to carray object.
How do I implement this without any deadlock?

Comment: I am observing the same behavior with scikit learn, it might be a bug in joblib